# Python: Type error when drawing contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

despite using the search function I've been unable to find an answer. I got two assumptions, but don't know in how far they may apply. Now the problem:

I'd like to plot a contour. For this I've got here the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi=list_of_distance
yi=list_of_angle

x = np.arange(0,54,0.2)
y = np.arange(0,180,2.0)

Z = np.histogram2d(xi,yi,bins=(274,90))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.ylabel('angles')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

xi and yi are lists containing float values. 
x and y are defining the 'intervals' ...for example:
x generates a list with values from 0 to 54 in 0.2 steps
y generates a list with values from 0 to 180 in 2.0 steps

with Z I make use of the numpy function to create 2D-Histograms. Actually this seems to be the spot that causes trouble.

When the function plt.contour(X,Y,Z) is called, the following error message emerges:

> ... File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2641, in **new**
>       _data = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, subok=True, ndmin=ndmin)
>   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Now to the assumptions what may cause this problem:

1. It seems like it expects an array but instead of an numpy-array it receives a list

or

2. We got a row that is shorter than the others (I came to that thought, after a collegue ran into such an issue a year ago - there it has been fixed by figuring out that the last row was by 2 elements shorter than all others...)

Comment: `x = np.arange(0,54,0.2)` will give you 270 items, but in your histogram you set 274 bins. Is this same in your code? The dimension mismatch might be this.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I've tested it by adapting it to 270, and also by completely removing the bins parameter. The error message still emerges.

Comment: @ Benjamin
Could you please write what you've edited? So that I won't make the mistake again :)

Answer (score 2):

As @rocksportrocker implies, you need to take into account that `histogram2d` returns the edges in addition to the histogram. Another detail is that you probably want to explicitly pass in a range, otherwise one will be chosen for you based on the actual min and max values in your data. You then want to convert the edges to cell centers for the plot. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000000                     # how many data points
xmin, xmax = 0.0, 54.0          # distances
ymin, ymax = 0.0, 180.0         # angles

# make up some random data
xi=np.random.normal(xmax/2.0, xmax/4.0, n)
yi=np.random.normal(ymax/3.0, ymax/3.0, n)

Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(xi,yi, bins=(270,90), range=[[xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax]])

# find the cell centers from the cell edges
x = 0.5*(xedges[:-1] + xedges[1:])
y = 0.5*(yedges[:-1] + yedges[1:])

# promote to 2D arrays
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)

plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.ylabel('angles')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("hist2d.png")
```

yields a countour plot like this:

[image: hist2d.png]

but personally I wouldn't use contours in this case, since the histogram is likely to be noisy.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback indicates that the error does not raise from the call to matplotlib, it is numpy which raises the ValueError.

Comment: *blush* apologies. I've to pay more attention to the traceback.

Interesting is the output of the 2d-histogram:

>(array([[...],
         [...],
          ...
         [...]]),
  array([[...],
         [...],
          ...
         [...]]))

So we got here a tuple, consisting of 2 arrays, that consist themselves of lists of lists. This seems strange. Maybe the error lies here within?

Comment: ahh, it's lightening up a bit:

"Returns
-------
H : ndarray, shape(nx, ny)
  The bidimensional histogram of samples x and y. Values in x are
  histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are histogrammed
  along the second dimension.
xedges : ndarray, shape(nx,)
  The bin edges along the first dimension.
yedges : ndarray, shape(ny,)
  The bin edges along the second dimension."

source: http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-2ac0606e08a8d035cb73baf482d15540556292a5

Comment: mhh, if the line plt.contour(X,Y,Z) is replaced with his:
plt.contour(X,Y,Z[0]) the previous error-message disappears, because we are getting now the 2D-histogramm that we want (which is stores in Z[0]).

The error-message that occurs now (and as it seems the last error-message ^^):

TypeError: Inputs x and y must be 1D or 2D.

But the output of X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
is for X and Y an array of arrays [[],[],[],...,[]]. So here it is difficult to recognize why it refuses to accept X and Y ...also casting : np.array(X) does not solve the problem